# MS Access Query using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I am executing a MS Access Query through c#. Below is the query

```
String SelWHQuery = "SELECT  DateDiff('n',INTime,OUTTime)\\60 & '.' & Format(DateDiff('n',[INTime],[OUTTime]) Mod 60,'00') AS Workedhours" + 
    "' WHERE EMPID = '" + Eno + 
    "'AND RDate=# "+ DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd") + 
    "# FROM  INOUTPunching";
```

which is giving below error

> {"The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."}

I need to know:

1. Why is this not working?
2. Is there any simplier method?

Comment: Looks like your query structure is incorrect, try to use this one: "SELECT ... FROM INOUTPunching WHERE ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the `FROM` clause before the `WHERE` clause. That is the problem with your query. And you have an extra single quote which should be removed. This is the query you should write:

```
String SelWHQuery = "SELECT  DateDiff('n',INTime,OUTTime)\\60 & '.' & Format(DateDiff('n',[INTime],[OUTTime]) Mod 60,'00') AS Workedhours FROM  INOUTPunching " + 
" WHERE EMPID = '" + Eno + 
"'AND RDate=# "+ DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd") + "#";
```

And about a simpler method: no, this is the simplest method but it is prone to SQL injection attacks. Replace it with a parameterized query (assuming you have an `OldDbCommand` name `cmd`):

```
String SelWHQuery = "SELECT  DateDiff('n',INTime,OUTTime)\\60 & '.' & Format(DateDiff('n',[INTime],[OUTTime]) Mod 60,'00') AS Workedhours FROM  INOUTPunching " + 
" WHERE EMPID = @EmpId AND RDate=# "+ DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd") + "#";

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = SelWHQuery;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Eno);
```

Comment: You are correct Alireza, its working. I want to mark as Answer.